# $\int_0^tf(s)ds < \infty$ for almost every $t\in [0,T)$ implies $f$ is integrable on $[0,T)$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Suppose a non-negative function $f : [0,T) \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies the following:

For almost every $t\in [0,T)$, 
$$\int_0^tf(s)ds < \infty.$$

Is there anything I can conclude? For instance, is $f$ integrable in $[0,T)?$

**EDIT**

Here I shall explain exactly where the problem comes from:

I have the following situation: let $\alpha : [0,T) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that
$\|\alpha\|^2_{L^2([0,s])} < \infty,~\text{for a.e. $s\in [0,T)$}.$

I would like to know if $\|\alpha\|_{L^2([0,T)} < \infty.$

How did I get it?

From the fact that on the problem I am working on, it holds
$$\int_0^T\|\alpha\|_{L^2([0,s)}ds \leq C,~C > 0.$$

Comment: I mean, what about $f(s)=\frac1{T-s}$ ?

Comment: @Gae.S. this is a good one. Does this statement give me any additional information other than the fact that $F(t) = \int_0^t f(s)ds$ is integrable?

Comment: I don't know if it gives you other information, but for sure it doesn't give you the fact you've just mentioned.

Comment: what does it mean for almost every ? Since $t$ the bound on the integral is a constant, you can't evaluate the fonction defined as the integral, can you?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy why not, isn't it the definition of being L1?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Though in this case the integrand is non-negative, therefore it synonymous with integrability on $[0,t)$.

Comment: Now that it's occurring to me, for $f\ge0$ having the condition $\int_0^t f(x)\,dx<\infty$ hold *almost everywhere* on $[0,T)$ is largely irrelevant: either it holds for all $t$ in the interval or it doesn't hold almost everywhere.

Comment: @Gae.S. I don't think I get it. You are saying that this info is irrelevant? That one can not conclude anything? I got confused.

Comment: @L.F.Cavenaghi I think Gae S as well as I do not understand the meaning of hold almost everywhere. If one defines the function defined as the integral, then you can't say f(x) = y, because f(x) can take any value since it's defined almost everywhere. Can you please define the meaning of almost everywhere here ? The definition you gave is not well defined. Or please explain it because I personally don't understand it.

Comment: @MarineGalantin I shall add some info,

Comment: @MarineGalantin, please, consider seeing the EDIT, as well Gae.

Comment: I don't share @MarineGalantin 's concern. I understand perfectly what it means for $\int_0^t f(s)\,ds<\infty$ to hold almost everywhere on $[0,T)$. I understand it to the point of observing that this condition is unnecessarily sophisticated for describing the situation. Since the integrand is non-negative, the function onto the extended real numbers $F(t)=\int_0^tf(s)\,ds$ is weakly increasing and the set $\{t\in [0,T)\,:\, F(t)<\infty\}$ will always be in the form $[0,\gamma)$ for some $0<\gamma\le T$. Therefore, "almost everywhere" is equivalent to "everywhere" here.

Comment: So you are saying the integral is finite everywhere? I dont see how it does not contradict your first example. Sorry to bother.

Comment: @L.F.Cavenaghi Well check if the assertion $\left[\forall t\in [0,T),\int_0^t \frac1{T-x}\,dx<\infty\right]$ is true and if the assertion $\left[\int_0^T \frac1{T-x}\,dx<\infty\right]$ is true. If it is not true that the first one is true and that the second one is false, then you got me.

Comment: @Gae.S., thanks a lot. If you post your penult comment as an answer I will accept it.